# Symfony getRepository() on null at a new server

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony 2.7.2. I did a copy of my website on a new webserver and faced a problem:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getRepository() on null (500 Internal Server Error)

At the string:

```
$repository  = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Meal');
```

It works fine at the old server and it does not work at the new one.
The only one thing I changed at the new server is unix_socket at config.yml and database username and password at parameters.yml

> unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: If you also copied the cache, it will still have the old username/password within it. Clear the cache and allow it to regenerate.

Comment: @AlisterBulman  thanks for the answer!
i run app/console cache:clear  and now i have another error at the browser: Warning: tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/user245/data:.)  
What does it mean?

Comment: @AlisterBulman  finally i cleared cache. It does not fix the problem.

Comment: take a look at this doc https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/setup/file_permissions.html